# Constexpr Factorial Compilation Results in VS2015 and GCC 5.4.0

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

Wondering if the following surprises anyone, as it did me?  Alex Allain's article [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-compile-time-processing-with-constexpr.html) on using constexpr shows the following factorial example:

```
constexpr factorial (int n)
{
    return n > 0 ? n * factorial( n - 1 ) : 1;
}
```

And states:

> Now you can use factorial(2) and when the compiler sees it, it can
>   optimize away the call and make the calculation entirely at compile
>   time.

I tried this in VS2015 in Release mode with full optimizations on (/Ox) and stepped through the code in the debugger viewing the assembly and saw that the factorial calculation **was not** done at compilation.

Using GCC v5.4.0 with --std=C++14, I must use /O2 or /O3 before the calculation is performed at compile time.  I was surprised thought that using just /O the calculation did not occur at compilation time.

Main main question is: Why is VS2015 not performing this calculation at compilation time?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the context of the function call.

For example, the following obviously could never be calculated at compile time:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
std::cout << factorial(x);
```

On the other hand, this context would *require* the answer at compile time:

```
class Foo {
    int x[factorial(4)];
};
```

`constexpr` functions are only guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time if they are called from a `constexpr` context; otherwise it is up to the compiler to choose whether or not to eval at compile time (assuming such an optimization is possible, again, depending on the context).

Comment: Your qualification is a bit strong: constexpr functions are only guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time if they are called in a constexpr context. The compiler is free to make the optimization anywhere else as it can or sees fit.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use it in const expression, as:

```
 constexpr auto res = factorial(2);
```

else computation can be done at runtime.

Comment: That is flat out incorrect; the computation can be done whenever the compiler is capable and decides to. Compilers were doing const propagation long before constexpr existed.

Comment: @NirFriedman: I didn't say that compiler has to compute at runtime otherwise, only that compiler **has to** compute at compile time in less places than one can expect. `constexpr` is not the only place, there are array size, template arguments ...

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yep, this appears to be the case.  When recompiling in VS2015 (/Ox) using constexpr in the construction of the return value results in the computation happening at compile time.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` is *neither* necessary *nor* sufficient to compile time evaluation of a function.

It's not sufficient, even aside from the fact that the arguments obviously also have to be constant expressions. Even if that is true, a conforming compiler does not have to evaluate it at compile time. It only has to be evaluated at compile time if it is in a constexpr context. Such as, assigning the result of the computation to a `constexpr` variable, or using the value as an array size, or as a non-type template parameter.

The other point, is that the compiler is completely capable of evaluating things at compile time, even without constexpr. There is a lot of confusion about this, and it's not clear why. compile time evaluation of `constexpr` functions fundamentally just boils down to constant propagation, and compilers have been doing this optimization since forever: https://godbolt.org/g/Sy214U.

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}

int foo() { return factorial(5); }
```

On gcc 6.3 with O3 (and 14) yields:

```
foo():
        mov     eax, 120
        ret
```

In essence, outside of the specific case where you absolutely force compile time evaluation by assigning a `constexpr` function to another constexpr variable, compile time evaluation has more to do with the quality of your optimizer than the standard.