# Best place for constant array declaration

Tags: c++

While attempting to write the fastest factorial function that evaluates at run-time, I found myself questioning whether it is a good idea to declare the constant array `f[]` at the function level or at the unit level.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cassert>  
// uint64_t const f[21] = { 1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800,39916800,479001600,6227020800, 87178291200, 1307674368000, 20922789888000, 355687428096000, 6402373705728000, 121645100408832000, 2432902008176640000 };

const uint64_t factorial(const uint8_t n) {
    static uint64_t const f[21] = { 1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800,39916800,479001600,6227020800, 87178291200, 1307674368000, 20922789888000, 355687428096000, 6402373705728000, 121645100408832000, 2432902008176640000 };
    assert(n <= 20);
    return f[n];
}
```

What are the pros and cons of each placement, assuming that `f[]` will be used only by the `factorial()` function ?

Is a constant, which is declared at the function level, created and destroyed each time the function is executed, like a non-const variable, or does the linker collect and put all constants in the `.rodata` section at compile-time?

Comment: The best way is constexpr.

Comment: Memoization and tail call are efficient optimization for factorial function. Use constexpr and let the compiler do it's magic

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135537/how-does-the-c-compiler-evaluate-recursive-constexpr-functions-so-quickly

Comment: To understand which is the "best" approach, one needs to understand the resulting difference. Can you answer the following question: what is the difference between declaring this array, both ways? What happens, differently, with one vs the other approach? Once you answer this question, you will then know what's the "best place" for this.

Comment: @ Tony Tannous: The writing of parameters to stack as well as writing and reading the return address to stack upon each recursive function call, does NOT make it the fastest regular function. Does the `constexpr function` calculate all the factorials at compile time and then uses a lookup table to obtain them at run-time?  How does it know not to calculate beyond `factorial(20)` at compile-time ?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik: These are good question but the answers to them is exactly the information I am seeking.  I was thinking that `const` arrays are put in the `.rodata` section by the linker when they are declared at the unit level...but I have no idea where they are stored when declared at the function level. Is it on the stack or in the `.rodata` section ?

Comment: @S.M.: Do you mean to use `constexpr` to declare the static array `f[]` or to use a `constexpr function` as a replacement for the entire `factorial()` function ?  In case you mean the latter, there are problems with it being evaluated as a normal function (with the overhead of run-time multiplication and burdening the stack with parameter/address saving/restoring) when NOT called form a `constexpr context`.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741519/constexpr-factorial-compilation-results-in-vs2015-and-gcc-5-4-0

Comment: This has nothing to do where the arrays are stored, whatsoever. It all has to do with when each alternative's array gets created and destroyed. If you don't know the difference between declaring something globally, versus local to the function, and what are the fundamental differences between the two alternatives, this should be explained in the introductory chapters of every C++ textbook.

Comment: I'd define the array inside the function to limit its visibility, `static` to specify its lifetime, and `const` because they're constant values.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I understand the argument about limiting the visibility of this constant. Could you elaborate more about its lifetime ?

Comment: Conceptually a non-static object is created every time the block is entered. By making it [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) you're saying it should be created/initialized once and then be the same object every subsequent time. Of course, with optimizations enabled the compiler might do that anyway but it's good to express your intent.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik: Yes, I know that a regular local variable is created and destroyed each time the function is executed, but I am not convinced that the same is true about constants. I heard that the linker collects and puts all constants in the .rodata section.

Comment: You can see it [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/64v4EG) **with no optimizations enabled**. If you make the array `static` then that call to `memcpy` goes away.

Comment: Well, don't believe everything you hear. There is no requirement like that, whatsoever, in the C++ standard, of anything like that. In fact, in the two thousand pages that make up the current C++ standard there's not a single mention of "the .rodata section". Therefore, if you'd like to maximize the chances of getting the best performance, one needs to avoid every opportunity for creating extra work in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion the best is to let the compiler decide and do evrything with constexpr. The compiler will make the best decision for you.

And because the number of factorials that will fit into an unsigned 64 bit value is very low (21), a compile time array will use mainly only 21*8 = 168 bytes.

**168 bytes**

That number is that low that we can build easily a compile time `constexpr std::array` and stop all further considerations.

Really everything can be done at compile time.

We will first define the default approach for calculation a factorial  as a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long n) noexcept {
    return n == 0ull ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1ull);
}
```

With that, factorials can easily be calculated at  compile time. Then, we fill a `std::array` with all factorials. We use also a `constexpr` and make it a template with a variadic parameter pack.

We use `std::integer_sequence` to create a factorials for indices 0,1,2,3,4,5, ....

That is straigtforward and not complicated:

```
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { factorial(ManyIndices)... } };
};
```

This function will be fed with an integer sequence 0,1,2,3,4,... and return a `std::array<unsigned long long, ...>` with the corresponding factorials.

We know that we can store maximum 21 values. And therefore we make a next function, that will call the above with the integer sequence 1,2,3,4,...,20,21, like so:

```
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
```

And now, finally,

```
constexpr auto Factorial = generateArray();
```

will give us a compile-time `std::array<unsigned long long, 21>` with the name Factorial containing all factorials. And if we need the i'th factorial, then we can simply write `Factorial[i]`. There will be no calculation at runtime.

I do not think that there is a faster way to calculate a factorial.

Please see the complete program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// All the below will be calculated at compile time
// constexpr factorial function
constexpr unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long n) noexcept {
    return n == 0ull ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1ull);
}
// We will automatically build an array of factorials at compile time
// Generate a std::array with n elements 
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { factorial(ManyIndices)... } };
};
// Max index for factorials for an 64bit unsigned value 
constexpr size_t MaxIndexFor64BitValue = 21;

// Generate the required number of elements
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
// This is an constexpr array of all factorials numbers
constexpr auto Factorial = generateArray();

// All the above was compile time
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Test function
int main() {
    for (size_t i{}; i < MaxIndexFor64BitValue; ++i)
        std::cout << i << '\t' << Factorial[i] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Developed, compiled and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2

Additionally compiled and tested with gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0.1

Language: C++17

Comment: So what happens when this is NOT called from a `constexpr context`.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741519/constexpr-factorial-compilation-results-in-vs2015-and-gcc-5-4-0

Comment: Maybe you have a misunderstanding. The function is called always at compile time to create a constexpr ````std::array````. And if that would be not possible then the compiler would emit an error. Later, this function will never be called.That's the whole point about it. So, we will not call the function, but lookup the value in the array. This will always work. There is no exception. And this is the absolut fastest way to get a factorial. If you call this function later (which you should not do) then it will always be executed at runtime, correct. But as said. Don't do that.

Comment: By NOT a `constexpr context` I meant something like this:  `std::cin >> x;` followed by 
`std::cout << Factorial(x);`

Comment: If you call it like ````std::cout << factorial(x);```` it will **always** be evaluated fully **runtime**. So, call it with ````std::cout << Factorial[x];````. Then you get the values evaluated at compile time. That's the secret. Use simple lookup in a compile time generated ````constexpr std::array````, instead of function call. Please carefully note the difference between  "factorial(x)" and "Factorial[x]"

Comment: Maybe as additional explanation: if you declare your "static uint64_t const f[21]" as constexpr, then you have the same solution. The only difference to my proposal is that I do not want to write "1,1,2,6,24,...", but let the compiler do that for me.